# When/why is the "persistentValue" updated?

Tags: grails

I think I'm missing something about isDirty. The method doSomething() returns false. Why?

```
class A {
    Integer x

    boolean doSomething() {
        callAMethodThatChangesPropertyX()
        callAMethodThatRunsACriteriaOverA()
        this.isDirty('x')
    }
```

Comment: There isn't enough information here.  Some relevant factors are whether or not the instance you are working with has already been persisted, which GORM implementation you are using and in what context are you invoking the `doSomething()` method.

Comment: The instance of A was already saved; using grails 2.5.3; doSomething is being called from a service method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate flush session during execution of `callAMethodThatChangesPropertyX()` or `callAMethodThatRunsACriteriaOverA()`. I'd rather bet on `callAMethodThatRunsACriteriaOverA()`, especially if you call in it some GORM queries. You can easily check it by trivial debugging:

```
boolean doSomething() {
    print this.isDirty('x')
    callAMethodThatChangesPropertyX()
    print this.isDirty('x')
    callAMethodThatRunsACriteriaOverA()
    print this.isDirty('x')
}
```

This behaviour is directly connected with FlushMode and [HibernateTransactionManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/HibernateTransactionManager.html). Depending on your Grails version [it may be different](https://grails.org/wiki/2.4.3%20Release%20Notes).

Comment: Thanks. The grails documentation (by the way, I'm using version 2.5.3) doesn't mention that flush "breaks" the isDirty method.